# File Upload API working with Postman but not with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, amazon-s3, jersey

I am going with file upload issue, in which I am using angular in front-end and Java at backend and uploading image on S3 bucket. I think there is no issue in java code because when I am using this upload URL on postman it is going well, I am Attaching Postman screenshot to showcase how it is working fine

[image: POSTMAN REQUEST SCREENSHOT]

Here is My ***AngularJS Controller*** as follows :

```
contactUs.controller('contactController', ['$scope','$http', 
function($scope,$http) {    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
var file = $scope.myFile;

           console.log('file is ' );
           console.dir(file);

           var uploadUrl = "uploadURL";

           var fd = new FormData(file);
           fd.append('files', file);

           $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
              transformRequest: angular.identity,
              headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                        'Authorization': 'Basic QHN0cmlrZXIwNzoxMjM0NTY='}
           })

           .success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
           })

           .error(function(error){
            console.log(error);
           });
        };
  }]);
```

Here is My ***AngularJS Directive*** as follows :

```
contactUs.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
           restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
              var modelSetter = model.assign;
              console.log(model);
              console.log(modelSetter);
              element.bind('change', function(){
                 scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                 });
              });
           }
        };
           }]);
```

The ***HTML*** is as follows :

```
<input type = "file" name="files" file-model = "myFile"/>
<button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
```

The **Java controller** is as follows :

```
@Path("/upload")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("application/text")
public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("files") List<FormDataBodyPart> bodyParts,@FormDataParam("files") FormDataContentDisposition fileDispositions) {
    /* Save multiple files */
    BodyPartEntity bodyPartEntity = null;
    String fileName = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts.size(); i++) {
        bodyPartEntity = (BodyPartEntity) bodyParts.get(i).getEntity();
        fileName = bodyParts.get(i).getContentDisposition().getFileName();
        s3Wrapper.upload(bodyPartEntity.getInputStream(), fileName);
    }
    String message= "File successfully uploaded !!";
    return Response.ok(message).build();
}
```

The ***Error*** I am getting with the AngularJS is below :

**400 - Bad Request**

Comment: I think this `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` is the problem. Setting the header doesn't add the boundary. You need to let the browser create the header. Not exactly sure how. If I recall, it might be something like setting the header to `false` or something like that. You should search for articles on sending files. I'm sure they discuss it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) To POST File data, You don't need to provide content-type as Multi part/form-data. Because It understand data type automatically. So just pass **`headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}`**.

2) As you show in your postman, key is **files** then If you are providing **`name="files"`** and **`fd.append("files",file)`**, It will not process as files key is on both side. So, Remove **`name="files"`** from HTML and process the upload file then.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I use following with `$http` to send multi-part form data. Please try this.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('files', file);
return $http.post(uploadUrl, formdata, { transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} });
```